# Where do I start in writing a promised based validation using javascript and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying a create a promised-base validation.
  My first idea is to have something as following:

```
export namespace Constraints {
  function required(value: any, vm: any, customParams: RequiredParams);
  function minLength(value: any, vm: any, customParams: LengthParams);
  function maxLength(value: any, vm: any, customParams: LengthParams);
}


 const ConstraintsInForm = {
  fields: {
    login: [
      { validator: Constraints .required },      
    ],
    password: [
      { validator: Constraints .required },
events: { onChange: true, onBlur: true },     
    ]
  }
};
```

Can I have an example of how I can write my own promised base validation as I passed in the constraints and the fields and their respective values?

I want to add flexibility as much as possible so that the constraintsInForm is dynamic and I just have to call a method and I have the corresponding errors.

Comment: Why promise-based? You have an asynchronous dependency?

Comment: @trincot what is the advantages and disadvantages of asynchronous dependency and promised-base?

Comment: What I mean is that if you don't *have* such dependency (i.e. an asynchronous API you might use), then there is really no reason to make your code asynchronous. Or if you see a reason, then please highlight that in your question. As it stands now, I would say "don't do it. Stick with synchronous code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the assumptions that your functions `required` and `minLength` and `maxLength` returns a bool

```
function required(value: any, vm: any, customParams: RequiredParams); 
function minLength(value: any, vm: any, customParams: LengthParams);
function maxLength(value: any, vm: any, customParams: LengthParams);
```

You could write a promise that way in Javascript

```
const ConstraintsInForm = {
  fields: {
    login,
    password,
  }
  events,     
};

const FieldPromise = (ConstraintsInForm) => {
  const fields = ConstraintsInForm.fields;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(required(fields.login) && required(fields.password)){
      // the user has filled in its credentials
      if(minLength(fields.login) && maxLength(fields.password)){
        // the password match min and max length constraints
        // so let's use this data
        resolve(fields);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    }
    else {
      reject();
    }
})}
```

This is a hint, you just need to do kind of the same in TypeScript